MongoDB documents are getting deleted prematurely despite removing TTL index
I have a MongoDB collection where I store documents using Mongoose in a Node.js application. Initially, I had set up a TTL (Time-To-Live) index on the schema to automatically delete documents after 2 mins. However, I later removed the TTL index as I no longer needed the automatic deletion. Surprisingly, documents are still getting deleted after approximately 2 minutes, despite the TTL index being removed.
I've double-checked my code, and I'm confident that the TTL index line has been removed from the schema definition. I've also ensured that there are no other TTL indexes applied to the collection. Additionally, I've reviewed the MongoDB server configuration and application logic, but I couldn't find any other factors causing the premature deletions.
Could anyone suggest potential reasons why documents are still being deleted prematurely after removing the TTL index? How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue to prevent documents from being deleted unexpectedly?
Before
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const BulletinBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    created_by_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      immutable: true,
    },
    updated_by_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    p_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Property",
      immutable: true,
    },
    post_text: String,
    post_images: [
      {
        name: String,
        data: String,
        size: Number,
        encoding: String,
        mimetype: String,
      },
    ],
    comment_count: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    like_count: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment",
      },
    ],
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
BulletinBoardSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 120 }); //2mins
const BulletinBoard = mongoose.model("BulletinBoard", BulletinBoardSchema);

module.exports = BulletinBoard;


After
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const BulletinBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    created_by_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      immutable: true,
    },
    updated_by_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    p_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Property",
      immutable: true,
    },
    post_text: String,
    post_images: [
      {
        name: String,
        data: String,
        size: Number,
        encoding: String,
        mimetype: String,
      },
    ],
    comment_count: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    like_count: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment",
      },
    ],
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const BulletinBoard = mongoose.model("BulletinBoard", BulletinBoardSchema);

module.exports = BulletinBoard;



If you are using an enterprise version of MongoDB, you can try to audit the delete events of those document to see what is causing the deletion

Can you use Compass to view the Indexes tab and see if you still have it. Otherwise use mongosh to view the collection and run getIndexes().

Removing an index from the mongoose schema doesn't necessarily drop it from the database -  have you checked the currently defined indexes on the collection?

Yes issue was resolved
I didn't know i have to drop the index if I have changed schema
My bad and Thanks for help
@Joe and jQueeny
